# Server throwing Error 500 when deploying Laravel App on Godaddy Subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, ftp

I've been having trouble uploading a Laravel app to a GoDaddy server. My root is located in `httpdocs`. Here is my current structure.

```
/app
/bootstrap
/vendor
/httpdocs --my public folder
.../packages
.../js
.../css
...other files
```

In my `bootstrap/paths.php` file:

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../httpdocs',
'base' => __DIR__.'/..',
```

In my `index.php` file:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';
```

When I browse to `mysubdomain.subdomain.com` I get an "Internal Service Error". What could be going wrong? I configured my paths correctly to point to the new folders.

Comment: I am stupid. I signed up for microsoft hosting instead of linux. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get rid of the 500:

My main web site (not the subdomains) has an `.htaccess` which does "RewriteEngine on" and some other stuff.  So I had to add this almost empty `.htaccess` to my subdomain folder:

> /public_html/sites/[subdomain-name]/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>
```

That fixed my 500 error but you still also need to route to the Laravel public folder...